# android intent: when can the action be null?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

In an already existing projects I see that a service checks if the intent is null and if the intent action is null.

I know that the intent action will be null if the service is invoked as:

```
context.startService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));
```

but I do not know whether or not the framework does such invocations.

**Does the system ever start a service with a null intent action?**

**Is it possible that a service is started with null intent?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does the system ever start a service with a null intent action?

Sure. That is called an explicit `Intent`, where you identify the specific component to be started. This is the sort of `Intent` that you should be using for your own private activities, services, etc.

> Is it possible that a service is started with null intent?

The service is always *created* using a non-`null` `Intent`. However, `onStartCommand()` may be called with a `null` `Intent`, if the service was re-created due to Android terminating the process due to low memory conditions, where the earlier process' instance of the service returned `START_STICKY` from its `onStartCommand()`.

Comment: Well, if the intent action is `null`, does that mean that the intent came from my application (or maybe another app knowing the class name?), or it could come from the system itself due to... what?

Comment: @18446744073709551615: If your service is exported, a third party can craft an explicit `Intent` that can be used to start (or bind) to your service.

Comment: And the system, does it use explicit intents?

Comment: @18446744073709551615: I have no idea what you mean by "the system" in this context, sorry.

Comment: I mean system = Android as opposed to my application and 3-rd party stuff. That is, is it possible that a service is invoked via an explicit intent (with null action) if my application did not do that and no 3-rd party stuff is installed?

Comment: @18446744073709551615: For ordinary general-purpose services, I cannot think of a scenario where that would happen. Various specialized services (e.g., `InputMethodService`, `NotificationListenerService`) could conceivably be invoked with an explicit `Intent` and a `null` action, though I don't know that are invoked that way.